# MongoDb conditional relationship

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Suppose I have following 4 collections:
1- posts
2- companies
3- groups
4- users
Bellow is my current structure in post:
[image]

and their relation is:

- A company has an owner and many other members (user collection).
- A group has many members (users).
- A user has many posts.
- A group has many posts that published by one of its members.
- A company has many posts that published by its owner or members.

Now i have a problem on storing relation of users, company, and group with posts collection.

Bellow is my current structure:

I have decided to have a field `postable` inside my post document, and has a `type` field that will be 'user', or 'group', or 'company', and two other fields `name`, and `id` that will be company/group `id` and company/group `name` in cases that post is belonged to company or group but not user means `type="group" || type="company"`.

Now how i can handle this to map `id` as FK of `group` and `company` collection  (one field FK of two collection) ?
Is it the right structure ?

Comment: I'm not sure I can see what is the problem/question here.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I have only two question. 1- Is my structure is good. 2- Is it possible to have a conditional FK field, that based on another fields value it will be FK of different collection?

Answer (score 2):

What you have here is a polymorphic association. In relational databases, it is commonly implemented with two fields, `postable_id` and `postable_type`. The type column defines which table to query and id column determines the record.

You can do the same in mongodb (in fact, that is what you came up with, minus the naming convention). But mongodb has a special field type precisely for this type of situations: [DBRef](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/#dbref-explanation). Basically, it's an upgraded id field. It carries not only the id, but also collection name (and database name).

> how i can handle this to map id as FK of group and company collection (one field FK of two collection)?

Considering that mongodb doesn't have joins and you have to load all references manually, I don't see how this is any different from a regular FK field. Just the collection name is stored in the type field now, instead of being hardcoded.

Comment: Good answer! One another question can i have extra fields inside `DBRef` ? Suppose i want to have some denormalised data of company/group something like company/group name.

Comment: @jones "can i have extra fields inside DBRef" - it looks theoretically possible, but most certainly is a bad idea. Haven't tried it myself.

Comment: What is your suggestion for my denormalised data?

Comment: @jones: you can store your denormalized data alongside your ref field(s)